# Map items of list in Ansible to different values

Tags: python, ansible, devops

Let's say I have the following input structure

```
domain: topdomain.com
subdomains:
  - name: foo
  - name: bar
```

And would like to have this output

```
domains:
  - name: foo.topdomain.com
  - name: bar.topdomain.com
```

Something which could be implemented for example in Python

```
domain = 'topdomain.com'

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squared = list(map(lambda x: x**2, items))

subdomains = [
  {
    'name': 'foo'
  },
  {
    'name': 'bar'
  }
]

domains = list(map(lambda sd: {'name': sd['name'] + '.' + domain}, subdomains))

print(domains)
```

How can this be done in Ansible using filters ? Ideally implementing anything custom or special ?

NOTE: I am not looking for how to map a list of object to a list of strings as can be done with `map(attribute='name') | map('regex_replace', ...'`

Answer (score 2):

Although it requires a small hack (i.e. `to_json | from_json` below) to [work around a still unfixed feature request in jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/158), the following playbook meets your requirements. Note that you will have to `pip install jmespath` on the controller machine because of the use of the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
 
  vars:
 
    domain: topdomain.com
     
    subdomains:
      - name: foo
      - name: bar
     
    domains_query: "[].{name: join('', [name,'.{{ domain }}'])}"
     
    domains: "{{ subdomains | to_json | from_json | json_query(domains_query) }}"
 
  tasks: 
    - name: Show the result
      debug:
        var: domains
```

And the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show the result] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "domains": [
        {
            "name": "foo.topdomain.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "bar.topdomain.com"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```